# Rendering empty cells/separators in FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native, user-interface, react-native-flatlist

I have this flat list:

```js
<FlatList
    data={orders}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    style={{ height: "100%", borderWidth: 1 }}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <ListItem
        {...item}
        onPress={(id) => alert(`touched ${id}`)}
    />
    )}
    ListEmptyComponent={() => (
    <Text>
        The list is empty.
    </Text>
    )}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Separator />}
/>
```

The separator component looks like this:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
  separator: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#e4e4e4",
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
  ...
});
const Separator = () => <View style={styles.separator} />;
```

When I render only a few items, the remainder of the `FlatList` looks totally empty (outlined in black). How do I make the `FlatList` render separators between empty items so it is clear there is a list there, even if it is (mostly) empty, and so it doesn't look so blank?

[image: Rendering only one item]
[image: Rendering a few items]

Answer (score 1):

That's how the `ItemSeparatorComponent` props works, it displays only when there's at least 2 elements, and adds your `Separator` component between the items. If you need to add it even if it's just one element you need to do it manually:

```
renderItem={({ item }) => (
    orders.length > 1 
       ? <ListItem
            {...item}
            onPress={(id) => alert(`touched ${id}`)}
          />
       : <>
           <ListItem
              {...item}
              onPress={(id) => alert(`touched ${id}`)}
           />
           <Separator />
         </>
)}
```